# Sort hash by order of keys in secondary array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, select, hash

I have a hash:

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" =>2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4}
```

And I have an array:

```
array = ["b", "a", "d"]
```

I would like to create a new array that is made up of the original hash values that correspond with original hash keys that are also found in the original array while maintaining the sequence of the original array. The desired array being:

```
desired_array = [2, 1, 3]
```

The idea here is to take the word "bad", assign numbers to the alphabet, and then make an array of the numbers that correspond with "b" "a" and "d" in that order.

Comment: Yes. Ruby is the language I am using.

Comment: Are you asking for the resulting value to also be "sorted" according to the order in the array? Hashes are an unordered collection of data (although some languages may implemented them with ordering), so ordering the result doesn't make a lot of sense, if you want the result to be a hash that is. If you want it to be a list of pairs, then it makes lots of sense.

Comment: I wasn't articulate enough in my question. I have edited it to make more sense.

Comment: Question is not clear. Why is `3` included in the `desired_array`? And why is `4` absent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) followed by [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), [for example](http://ideone.com/FSFwh5):

```
hash = {"d" => 4, "b" =>2, "c" => 3, "a" => 1}
order = ["b", "a", "d"]

# For each key in order, create a [key, value] pair from the hash.
# (Doing it this way instead of filtering the hash.to_a is O(n) vs O(n^2) without
#  an additional hash-probe mapping. It also feels more natural.)
selected_pairs = order.map {|v| [v, hash[v]]}
# For each pair create a surrogate ordering based on the `order`-index
# (The surrogate value is only computed once, not each sort-compare step.
#  This is, however, an O(n^2) operation on-top of the sort.)
sorted = selected_pairs.sort_by {|p| order.find_index(p[0]) }

p sorted

# sorted =>
# [["b", 2], ["a", 1], ["d", 4]]
```

I've *not* turned the result back into a Hash, because I am of the belief that hashes should *not* be treated as having any sort of order, except for debugging aids. (Do keep in mind that Ruby 2 hashes are ordered-by-insertion.)

Comment: If I understand his question correctly, you will also need to filter the result values by the values in the array. With his given example, you should not have "c" in the result.

Comment: Or more likely, filter the input hash by the values in the array, then perform the operation that you described here.

Comment: @isomarcte Ah, good call. I missed that. Also fixed some blatant errors.

Comment: This is far away from the OP's desired output.

Comment: @sawa The OP changed the desired results. In any case the building blocks are there.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is a little unclear I'm assuming you want desired_array to be an array (you say you want a new array and finish the sentence off with new hash).  Also in your example I'm assuming you want desired_array to be [2, 1, 4] for ['b', 'a', 'd'] and not [2, 1, 3] for ['b', 'a', 'c'].

You should just you the [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method to create a array that will map the first array to the your desired array like so:

```
desired_array = array.map { |k| hash[k] }
```

You should familiarize yourself with the [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method, it's quite the handy method. From the rubydocs for the method: Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum. So in this case we are iterating through array and invoking hash[k] to select the value from the hash and creating a new array with values selected by the hash. Since iteration is in order, you will maintain the original sequence.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `values_at`:

```
hash.values_at *array
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable methods map, each works perfect

**desired_array = array.map { |k| hash[k] }
or
desired_array = array.each { |k| hash[k] }**